# Docker how to get shell on a container that exits fast

Tags: bash, docker

I have an issue with a container that causes it to exit immediately. I usually run this command on the problematic container to get a shell inside them and investigate the issue.

```
docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash
```

But if the container fails almost immediately, this does not work.

How can I easily *enter* into the exited container so that I can find the problem?

Comment: I think you should add some logging to your processes and stream it to `stdout`. That would make your life easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Way**:

```
docker run -it <container_name> sleep 20200202
```

Then try

```
docker exec -it <container_name> bash
```

If you have any entrypoint defined:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint "" <container_name> bash
```

You can also use other approaches of redirecting your command output to `/dev/null` ... so `stdout` never reads an exit. However the above approach is pretty straight forward and can be replicated using compose file as well.

NOTE: if you still want to run the `<someCommandWhichExists>` just run it on bash terminal that gets open up.

**Second Way**:

Let us say `xcontainerid` container already exited from output of `docker ps -a`.

If you are trying to get into this particular container, Just hit:

`docker commit xcontainerid ximagename`
`docker run -it --entrypoint "" ximagename bash`

This `ximagename` will have the exact environment as of your exited `xcontainerid`.